# max/min function in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to set the height of an element. It should be the height of the highest child element.

Is there something like:

```
Parent {
    height: max(child1.height, child2.height)
}
```

Alternatively something like:

```
Parent {
    height: stretchToChildren
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Math.max()` is variadic (taking arbitrarily many arguments).

Depending on actual layout, it might be possible to use `Item.childrenRect` property.

Answer (score -4):

```
Item {
  width: childrenRect.width // width is now 100
  height: childrenRect.height // height is now 100

  Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 100
  }
}
```

Here is example, how to work childrenRect